# How to list rows in an Oracle table where two columns contain the same value?

Tags: oracle

I am working in oracle database and I am  facing some difficulties. I have two columns as example A and B some of A's records have same values in B, so I want to find which in  A that  have same values in B I. For better understand check the example below.

For example, how I can find which records in (COL1) that have same values in (COL2) as example CRQ13423 and CRQ19876 both have same **ARN767**

```
      COL1            COL2    
---------------------------
1    -    CRQ14352    -       ARN011       
2    -    CRQ17672    -       ARN068      
3    -    CRQ13423    -       ARN767       
4    -    CRQ18782    -       ARN666              
5    -    CRQ19876    -       ARN767
```

Comment: What about [`where clause`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2134734)?

Comment: For your example, is that one result or two results (both CRQ13423 and CRQ19876)?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `COUNT` here as an analytic function:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COL2) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT COL1, COL2
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```